# I have a class autowired and it is having session factory

Tags: java, session, autowired

```
@Service
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AddToCartService {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AddToCartService.class);

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfig.class);

    public boolean  addToCart(long customerId, ArrayList<AddToCart>cart)
    {
        Query query =null;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        boolean status=false;
        Customer cus=null;
        Product product=null;
        AddToCart cartItem=null;
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            query = session.createQuery("delete  from AddToCart where customer_id="+customerId);
            query.executeUpdate();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.beginTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class autowired and it is having session factory but I need one more class externally and through that I will create a session and connect the db using properties file.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: I have 2 Databases- A and B.I need to configure the session factory to a particular database based on Admin selection in a JSP page.I have used a property file which will store the Admin selection and using it i need to configure the SessionFactory. can u pls help on this